# Reading a codeigniter cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I am making some web pages that take a wizard format and i want to remember the previous page,so i am storing data in a cookie. The default codeigniter cookie `ci_session`.

Once i get the user input,i save it in a cookie and go to the next step

```
$posted_identifier = $this->input->post('new_account');
    $this->session->set_userdata('identity'.rand(), $posted_identifier);
```

In the end,my cookie looks like

```
a:13:{s:10:"session_id";s:32:"6cb4cae70007f6e2b58ba147c57c7368";s:10:"ip_address";s:7:"0.0.0.0";s:10:"user_agent";s:72:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0";s:13:"last_activity";i:1421961876;s:9:"user_data";s:0:"";s:8:"identity";s:7:"jjkjlkm";s:13:"identity11027";b:0;s:13:"identity25967";s:3:"uio";s:13:"identity25434";s:3:"789";s:13:"identity10013";b:0;s:13:"identity29325";b:0;s:12:"identity4963";b:0;s:13:"identity23334";b:0;}59166fb25addef85e48447ae8dde7b9e
```

and i tried this

```
$json =  $this->input->cookie('ci_session', TRUE);
var_dump(json_decode($json,TRUE));
```

but it gives me `null`. Isn't the cookie in json format and how can i read the values of names that are called `identity` or at least contain `identity`?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not JSON but a serialized string. Try:

```
print_r(unserialize($cookie_string));
```

which should result in

```
Array
(
[session_id] => 6cb4cae70007f6e2b58ba147c57c7368
[ip_address] => 0.0.0.0
[user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0
[last_activity] => 1421961876
[user_data] =>
[identity] => jjkjlkm
[identity11027] =>
[identity25967] => uio
[identity25434] => 789
[identity10013] =>
[identity29325] =>
[identity4963] =>
[identity23334] =>
)
```